# How can I find the sentence length for every text in corpus?

Tags: python, python-2.7, corpus

Only **len(mycorpus.sents(fileid)**) does not seem to work (AssertionError), but it does work when I use it on Gutenberg: len(gutenberg.sents(fileid)). I am trying to find the sentence length of every text in my corpus, so that I can calculate the average sentence length per text. Is there a way to achieve this with my own corpus?

```
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
corpus_root = 'root'
mycorpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*.txt', encoding='utf-8')
mycorpus.fileids()
for fileid in mycorpus.fileids():
    num_chars = len(mycorpus.raw(fileid))
    num_words = len(mycorpus.words(fileid))
    num_sents = len(mycorpus.sents(fileid))
    num_vocab = len(set([w.lower() for w in mycorpus.words(fileid)]))
    print (num_chars / num_words), (num_words / num_sents), (num_words / 
    num_vocab), fileid
```